# Server Sent Events filtering on frontend side

Tags: javascript, java, server-sent-events, polling

I ve got the following situation:

[image]

Multiple users may concurrently establish a connection through a Javascript-based frontend to my Java-based backend service. Afterwards, the Java backend may gather messages from a queue and needs to inform the respective user of a "business event" related to a certain business case read from the queue. But only a subset of the users should be notified by a Server Sent Event (SSE).

Currently, I'm polling the backend regularly to know if for the respective business cases I am looking at, e.g. with ID A, B, C etc. will have new data that needs to be shown to the user. This is super inefficient and I was thinking about using SSEs as an alternative.

Since I don't want to introduce session handling at all, i will have to filter all the incoming events according to the case id (A, B, C, ... ) on the frontend side, but essentially any frontend that established a connection may read all events published.

While above scenario might be ok for certain use cases, what if the SSE contained sensitive information, e.g. private/personal data that User 1 should receive, but User 2 or 3 should not see at all in their browsers while inspecting deeper? Filtering on the frontend seems super bad in this case.

Am i misusing SSE here? Are there better alternatives to inform the frontend about changes in backend?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer myself. If I want to keep information private, I should never send any information out to the frontend(s) and rather filter out on the backend side beforce sending events out.

Opening the connection may be done in a parametrized way, e.g.
on path `/sse/{id}` and on the backend side, when handling this connection, while reading the user-information from the established connection, the backend should simply *not* publish any information on this channel.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the proposed ideology, your data can be handled on either side. Although handling business logic in the client, isn't the best idea, I've seen quite a few cases in which the backend developer doesn't like, nor is interested in, handling some of the business-related logic, thus the only possible solution is to handle them in the frontend.

In a case that the data (in your case, events) might contain confidential information, there are at least four possible options (excluding the (long-)polling mechanism):

1. Session Management in the Backend

   This option is pretty self-explanatory, you must create some sort of
   session management in the backend to keep track of who's who, thus
   being able to send the proper events to the right person.
2. Creating a middle-man to handle such information

   Although this isn't the cleanest solution, if you're not the person in charge of the backend, and he isn't helping you in your case, it's better not to screw the security of the users and create a middle-man webserver (which means you have to manage the sessions as well).
3. Using encryption

   In theory, it's possible to create an encryption protocol in which only the right client, with the appropriate private key, can decode the message. However, the implementation of such a mechanism requires a lot more code, and at its best can reduce the headache of creating a complex (and usually, dynamic) session handling infrastructure.
4. Don't do anything

   In case you're forced to complete the feature as soon as possible, just create something that works, but be sure to try replacing it with a proper implementation before it hits the production branch.

Probably, it's one of the most abstract answers that I've written on StackOverflow, but hopefully, it can help you to handle this situation more gracefully.